Column Headers in Union query results
Just discovering Union queries. I'm trying to convert an Excel table, linked to my DB, into a normal Select query. I have been reading prior posts on this forum and have managed to get almost there. What I can't work out is, how to include the column headers in the body of the query.
Code used
SELECT DailyClosePrices.Pricedate, DailyClosePrices AFI As ClosePrice
FROM DailyClosePrices
UNION
SELECT DailyClosePrices.Pricedate, DailyClosePrices ARG
FROM DailyClosePrices
UNION
SELECT DailyClosePrices.Pricedate, DailyClosePrices A200
FROM DailyClosePrices

Table and query samples attached, showing current results and required outcome. Any help would be much appreciated.
Table & Query samples (https://i.sstatic.net/3iRM0tlD.png)

To UNPIVOT table, take column name as new column value ("AFI" as FuncCode).
See example
SELECT DailyClosePrices.Pricedate, "AFI" as FuncCode, AFI As ClosePrice
FROM DailyClosePrices
UNION
SELECT DailyClosePrices.Pricedate, "ARG" as FuncCode, ARG as ClosePrices
FROM DailyClosePrices
UNION
SELECT DailyClosePrices.Pricedate, "A200" as FuncCode,A200 as ClosePrices
FROM DailyClosePrices


Worked a treat, thanks. One other follow up question, values are shown as varying range of decimal places. How do I enter a code to convert all to currency and nominated decimal places?

As usual, Format(xVal,"##,##0.000000000")
